# Selection Transform as Text/Title

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

How can I display a transform over selected points as text within a title or subtitle?

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "width": 800,
  "title": {
    "text": "Google's stock price over time.",
    "subtitle": "selected average: ???"
  },
  "selection": {
    "interval": {
      "type": "interval",
      "encodings": ["x"]
    }
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

A sum transformation does not lend itself to any graphical/visual representations. An idea is to have it  as a selection tooltip, but that [is not possible](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3154). So I settle for a subtitle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to insert a computed value within a subtitle, but you can achieve the same effect using a layer chart with a text mark that contains a computed value.

For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegM5QHsBjAa1wDojcA3EAXwBoQpkIA7XAMwOQFt4A2qE4BLVFACmyDJCiJe5XAE9eAIwKoAvNoDkAcQDyBvTvoBdJgHcRYKAAt4ADgAMzplBFRUE+KEkAPKAw9AgIAc28dXAACfGISaIAHZBEiCWiCailoj14JcnomVAglKUE-Vg5uPnKQUXEyhBBcCW8iDwI2DBE2SWRqCHQ6RlAIMLDkCTDoHzghEAJEjFx5ECZRVrAMZNSfJghcDEIYVAB9HbTzOgsQXghkEiOJQLWQCTYiAjAesN8Qfz+A1QiFmABZXIwQEpAYMQfAALQARmckICQSaG1QWzgzAIJ3OKUu7iUiVmIAAjoh2B4YB4svRhgxQHcHtsCD0gkx3p9vmxfk0ARiRJsZDNXlASWTJLxEjxBoUoX9MdiQBc9sxJRhKdTPNARPTGc1WhJ2iJOn8OVIgX8JaTur0rfKuR8vj9DnN-iAzMNrnQgA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "width": 800,
  "title": {"text": "Google's stock price over time."},
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"selection": "interval"}},
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "price", "as": "total_price"}]}
      ],
      "mark": "text",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"value": 400},
        "y": {"value": -10},
        "text": {"field": "total_price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {"interval": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}}
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Note that the text layer has `x` and `y` encoding values specified in pixels from the upper left of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say there are two possible approaches, but then @jakevdp post [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265299/2626865), so I guess there are now three.

1. Use an `ExprRef` in `title.subtitle`. While that isn't explicitly supported in the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/title.html) it doesn't make sense that only `title.text` would support an `ExprRef`. So I gave it a shot, and it works. Though the Vega editor will still raise schema validation warnings. I have a more involved example below using binned data.
2. 1. Filter and aggregate the selection. This will modify the current data stream and Vega-Lite doesn't support more than one data stream (unless using layers), so you'll have to patch the generated Vega.
   2. Access the text mark of the title using `title.encode.subtitle.update.text`. Once again, necessary to patch the generated Vega. (This was on the assumption that a subtitle couldn't be an `ExprRef`).

The neat thing about (2) is that it allows adding a text mark to the [selection mark](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection-mark.html), so the text could be made to follow the selection. That said that's possible with @jakevdp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265299/2626865) as well, and his answer is much simpler.

---

JavaScript loader ensuring that nothing runs out-of-order:

```js
%%javascript

function loadjs(ls, o) {
    let i = 0;
    let b = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#jupyter-config-data').text)["baseUrl"];
    ls = ls.reduce((a,l) => {
        if (!l.path)
            return a;
        let p = l.path;
        if (l.local)
            p = "/" + [b,"/files",p].map(s => s.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/, "")).filter(i => i).join("/");
        if (document.querySelector("script[src='" + p + "']"))
            return a;
        return [...a, p]; 
    }, [])
    function load() {
        if (i >= ls.length)
            return o();
        let t = document.createElement("script");
        [t.type, t.src, t.onload] = ["text/javascript", ls[i], (i+1>=ls.length) ? o : load];
        i = i+1;
        document.head.appendChild(t);
    }
    return load();
}
window.loadjs = loadjs
```

JavaScript loader for the JupyterLab cell as an IPython magic:

```py
import IPython
import IPython.core.magic as ipymagic

@ipymagic.magics_class
class LoadJSMagics(ipymagic.Magics):

    @ipymagic.cell_magic
    def loadjs(self, line, cell):
        js = f"loadjs({line}, () => {{\n{cell}\n}});"
        return IPython.display.Javascript(js)

IPython.get_ipython().register_magics(LoadJSMagics)
```

Jinja templating for JupyterLab cells as an IPython magic:

```py
import jinja2
import IPython
import IPython.core.magic as ipymagic

@ipymagic.magics_class
class JinjaMagics(ipymagic.Magics):

    @ipymagic.cell_magic
    def jinja(self, line, cell):
        t = jinja2.Template(cell)
        r = t.render({k:v for k,v in self.shell.user_ns.items() if k not in self.shell.user_ns_hidden})
        IPython.get_ipython().run_cell(r)
        #d = getattr(IPython.display, line.strip(), IPython.display.display)
        #return d(r)

IPython.get_ipython().register_magics(JinjaMagics)
```

Generate some example temporal data in Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c1 = np.random.randint(1,6, size=15)
c2 = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-01-15")
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": c2, "value": c1})
df = df.drop([2, 5,6,7,13])
df
```

The necessary imports:

```py
# Convert the Pandas dataframe to a format suitable for Vega-Lite.
import altair
# Tag Vega-Embed div's with UUIDs ensuring the correct div is targeted.
import uuid
import json

vega_libs =\
    [ {"path": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"}
    , {"path": "/libs/vega-lite@4-fix.js", "local": True}
    , {"path": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"}
    ]
```

The Vega-Lite:

```py
s =\
  { "title":
    { "text": "Daily Counts"
    , "subtitle": {"expr": "selectionSum(data('interval_store'), data('data_0'))"}
    , "subtitleFont": "monospace"
    }
  , "mark": "bar"
  , "encoding":
    { "x":
      { "type": "temporal"
      , "bin": "binned"
      , "field": "start"
      , "axis": { "tickCount": "day" }
      }
    , "x2": {"field": "end"}
    , "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"}
    }
  , "selection":
    { "interval":
      { "type": "interval"
      , "encodings": ["x"]
      }
    }
  , "transform":
    [ # Convert 'day' from 'string' to timestamp ('number')
      {"calculate": "toDate(datum.day)", "as": "day"}
      # Provide "start" and "end" as Date objects to match the
      # type of temporal domain objects
    , {"calculate": "timeOffset('hours', datum.day, -12)", "as": "start"}
    , {"calculate": "timeOffset('hours', datum.day, 12)", "as": "end"}
    ]
  , "height": 250
  , "width": "container"
  , "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json"
  , "config": {"customFormatTypes": "True"}
  , "data": altair.utils.data.to_values(df)
  }
```

And finally running the Vega-Lite:

```js
%%jinja
%%loadjs {{json.dumps(vega_libs)}}

{% set visid = uuid.uuid4() %}

element.innerHTML = `
    <style>.vega-embed.has-actions {width:90%}</style>
    <div id="vis-{{visid}}"></div>
`

var spec = {{json.dumps(s)}}

vega.expressionFunction("selectionSum", function(selection, data) {
    var view = this.context.dataflow;
    
    function intersects(i1, i2) {
        return (i1[1] >= i2[0] && i1[0] <= i2[1]);
    }
    
    function cmp_interval_pt(i0, i1, p) {
        if (i1 < p)
            return -1;
        if (i0 > p)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    
    function cmp_primitive(a,b) {
        if (a < b)
            return -1
        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    function bisect_left(l, v, fc=cmp_primitive) {
        return _bisect_left(l, 0, l.length, v, fc);
    }

    function _bisect_left(l, l0, l1, v, fc) {
        if (l1 <= l0)
            return l0;
        var i = Math.floor((l0+l1)/2);
        var c = fc(l[i], v);
        if (c < 0)
            l0 = i + 1;
        else
            l1 = i;
        return _bisect_left(l, l0, l1, v, fc);
    }

    function bisect_right(l, v, fc=cmp_primitive) {
        return _bisect_right(l, 0, l.length, v, fc);
    }

    function _bisect_right(l, l0, l1, v, fc) {
        if (l1 <= l0)
            return l0;
        var i = Math.floor((l0+l1)/2);
        var c = fc(l[i], v);
        if (c <= 0)
            l0 = i + 1;
        else
            l1 = i;
        return _bisect_right(l, l0, l1, v, fc);
    }
    
    function cmp_data(lv, v) {
        return cmp_interval_pt(lv.start, lv.end, v);
    }
    
    function constant_len_digits(s,l) {
        return " ".repeat(Math.max(0, l-s.toString().length)) + s
    }
        
    if (selection.length) {
        var r = selection[0]["values"][0];
        var d0 = bisect_left(data, r[0], cmp_data);
        var d1 = bisect_right(data, r[1], cmp_data);
        var s = data.slice(d0,d1).reduce((a,v)=>a+v.value, 0);
    }
    else
        var s = 0
    return `selected: ${constant_len_digits(s,3)}`;
});

vegaEmbed('#vis-{{visid}}', spec).then(function(result) {
}).catch(console.error);
```

And the result:

[image: final result: binned temporal bar graph with selection sum as subtitle]

Note that when it comes to coloring and selecting binned regions, you'll have to calculate the intersections yourself.